# Php database models

Tags: php, oop, class, object, model

```
<?php
 class ann {

      public function __construct($context, $orgs_id, $created_at) {
         $this->context = $context;
         $this->orgs_id = $orgs_id;
         $this->created_at = $created_at;
     }

     function create(){
         $createann = mysql_query("INSERT INTO anns(context,
 orgs_id, created_at)
 VALUES('$this->context',
 $this->orgs_id, '$this->created_at'");
         if($createann) echo "Duyuru Başarıyla Eklendi"; else echo "Duyuru
 Eklenemedi";
     }
     function read($id){
         $readann = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM anns WHERE id = $id");
         $context = mysql_result($readann,0, "context");
         $orgs_id = mysql_result($readann,0, "orgs_id");
         $created_at = mysql_result($readann,0,
 "created_at");

         $ann = new ann($context, $orgs_id, $created_at);

         return $ann;
     }
     function update($id, $context){
         $updateann = mysql_query("UPDATE anns SET context =
 '$context' WHERE id = $id");
         if($updateann) echo "Update success"; else echo
 "Update failed";
     }
     function delete($id){
         $deleteann = mysql_query("DELETE FROM anns WHERE id
 = $id");
         if($deleteann) echo "Delete success"; else echo "Delete not success";
     }
     //crud fonksiyonlari burda bitiyor 
}

?>
```

There is something wrong with our logic here but we are very new to php. We tried to create rails like models, but it think something with our class-object notation is wrong. So the code did not work. We cannot even create any object with it.
Thank you guys

Comment: Your code's comment at the bottom removes the closing } for the class.  Is this mistake just in the post?

Comment: yes it was just a mistake in the post, thanks for pointing out

Comment: thanks injection warnings but we are using a filter before the strings arrive to object creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`context`, `orgs_id` and `created_at` <s>must be</s> should be first declared either as public, private or protected before you use them.

In your `create` method, you don't filter user input. This may cause to your application SQL injection, you have to you always filter user input. Use either [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) or prepared statment by [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php).

You may check this [tutorial](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Object-Oriented-Programming-with-PHP.html).

Answer (score 0):

two things (which maybe only apply to your codesample here):

1. In your sample, you dont close your
   Class, because the last "}" is
   commented out.
2. You never opened a connection to your database, so the query would fail.

Answer (score 0):

a few observations:

declaring the attributes in the constructor is possible, but it's not elegant. I'd rather do:

```
class ann {
  private $context;
  private $orgs_id;
```

the "->" operator won't work inside a string. You'll need to concatenate the query:

```
"INSERT INTO anns(context,orgs_id, created_at) VALUES('".$this->context."',".$this->orgs_id".", '".$this->created_at."'"
```

but be careful on [sql injection](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

The rest should be fine! Good Luck.

Comment: You can use object operators inside strings if you wrap them in {} e.g "Property value is {$object->property}";

Comment: There's also a very good tutorial about good PHP OOP practices here: http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/oo-php-part-2-boring-oo-principles